# How to solve the "unable to find an inherited method for function" error when converting xml to data frame?

Tags: r, xml

So I have this package and function to mine data frames in the form of xml, and I've tried converting the xml to a single data frame but I'm not being able to. I used this code:

```
library(bold)
library(XML)
library(dplyr)
xml = bold_seqspec(taxon=c("carnivora"), format = "xml", marker="COI-5P")
df= xmlToDataFrame(xml , stringsAsFactors = FALSE,) %>% 
  mutate_all(~type.convert(., as.is = T))
```

However I'm getting the following error in the "xmlToDataFrame" function:

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘xmlToDataFrame’ for signature ‘"xml_document", "missing", "missing", "missing", "missing"’
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the xml is in a deeply nested list structure with variable length members, so it is not possible to automatically coerce it into a rectangular data structure (i.e. a data frame).

It is possible to extract the data you want in various ways, but you will need to decide which fields you want from each record and what to do if there are multiple entries in a single field, etc.

I would suggest you start by converting the xml to a list using `xml2::as_list` and exploring its contents using `str` to see which fields you want. You can then create a dataframe with the fields you want for each record.

For example:

```r
library(bold)
library(XML)
library(dplyr)
xml <- bold_seqspec(taxon=c("carnivora"), format = "xml", marker="COI-5P")
df <-  xml2::as_list(xml)
df <- df$bold_records
result <- do.call(rbind, lapply(df, function(x)
{
  data.frame(specimen = x$specimen_identifiers$sampleid[[1]],
             order = x$taxonomy$order$taxon$name[[1]],
             nucleotides = x$sequences$sequence$nucleotides[[1]],
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}))
```

Now `result` looks like this:

```
tibble::as_tibble(result)
#> # A tibble: 4,577 x 3
#>    specimen   order    nucleotides                                                     
#>    <chr>      <chr>    <chr>                                                           
#>  1 T-2294     Carnivo~ ---CCTGTACCTCTTATTCGGTGCGTGAGCCGGAATGGCGGGAACCGCCCTTAGCCTACTGAT~
#>  2 HBL008245  Carnivo~ NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN~
#>  3 HBL008385  Carnivo~ ACTCTTTACCTTTTATTTGGCGCATGAGCCGGAATAGTAGGCACTGCATTAAGCCTATTGATT~
#>  4 HBL008419  Carnivo~ NNTTTATATTTGCTATTCGGGGCATGAGCCGGTATAGTAGGCACTGCCCTAAGCCTCCTAATT~
#>  5 HLC-10619  Carnivo~ ACCCTTTACCTCTTATTCGGTGCATGAGCCGGAATAGTAGGAACTGCCCTCAGTCTTCTAATC~
#>  6 ROM 101864 Carnivo~ ACTCTCTACCTTCTATTCGGGGCTTGGGCTGGAATAGTGGGCACCGCTCTCAGCCTACTAATT~
#>  7 ROM 93093  Carnivo~ ACTTTGTATTTATTATTTGGAGCATGAGCCGGCATAGTAGGTACCGCCCTGAGCCTTCTTATC~
#>  8 bLpa138    Carnivo~ CCCTGCTATATCTCAATACCAAACACCCCTATTCGTCTGATCTGTTTTAATCACTGCTGTTCT~
#>  9 Fge20      Carnivo~ CCCTGCCATATCTCAATATCAAACACCTCTCTTCGTCTGATCTGTCTTAATTACTGCTGTTTT~
#> 10 bCth05     Carnivo~ TTCGCTGCCCCCTCAATAATAGGCCTTCCTATTGTAATCCTAATCATTATATTCCCATCCATT~
#> # ... with 4,567 more rows
```

Comment: The code works perfectly but when using "as_tibble" I get only 3 columns in the data frame, and when I use the function "bold_seqspec" with "format="tsv"" I get 81 columns. Before you convert it to tibble, the list result seems to hold all the information I wanted but I can't get it to unlist properly
thanks for the answer

Comment: @tadeufontes yes, this is what I explained in my answer. As an example, I chose three fields from each record to put in the dataframe, because you cannot simply unlist the whole list and call it a dataframe: each record has a different number of entries, so the data is not in a rectangular format.